# HTML5 form input pattern regex is not behaving as expected

Tags: regex, html, passwords

I am using regex101 as a baseline for correct javascript regex. Here is my pattern:

`/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,40}/g`

I am trying to create a password regex that is between 8-40 characters, with any characters but at least one number and at least one alphabet character.

On [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uRhO5l/1), this pattern works as expected. `asdf1234` correctly is matched.

However, trying to use this pattern in html5 form input pattern does not match the same results.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33mvu5sq/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the regex literal in HTML5 pattern attribute, it only accepts a string pattern (the `/` symbols on both ends in your pattern are treated as literal slashes).

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,40}$" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Note that the `^` and `$` in this pattern are not required as the regex in HTML5 pattern is anchored by default, but are OK to use (it will be easier to debug using regex101 or similar service).

Comment: wonderful! Thank you! I'm surprised this isn't documented more in top search results - They don't use slashes in examples, but also don't call it out that they are not needed.